# Remote login with token instead of credentials - is it a good idea?

Tags: php, security, authentication, cryptography, token

I'm not a cryptographer and if I had found something else I probably wouldn't try to solve this myself, so what do you think about this method to remotely login to a website from another site using a token instead of credentials?

I'll actually be glad if somebody points out a proven solution as this is just another homebrew.

- Site A (which I want to login to) uses a secret code, e.g. d4ffa3793[...]392258e6a.
- Site B (the one with the login-button) knows this code as well.
- When I click "login" on site B, B takes this secret and encrypts it with the timestamp of the current hour* using PHP's crypt function.
- The visitor is sent to site A with the resulting token, where site A does the same thing as site B to verify the token. If they match, it logs the user in.

*I'm using the timestamp of the current hour as some servers have slightly different times and it takes a while between generating and validating the token,

So, how is this? What would you suggest?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well that certainly will fail around the change of hours...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's true. That's why I set it to an hour and not less as this would increase failure.

Comment: And you call that a solution? To answer your question: something that fails predictably (even if only in some cases) certainly is _not_ a good idea.

Comment: The timestamp part is not particularly problematic, you can just send it as an extra plaintext parameter to site B. B then first checks that the plaintext timestamp matches the encoded one, then checks that the timestamp is not too old.

Comment: Oh, sure - that totally makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is not security-sensitive (i.e. you won't get into big trouble even if someone does figure out how to exploit the cross-login mechanism to steal the account of another user) then I would handle it pretty much like you said: create a token by hashing/encrypting username + timestamp + shared secret, send token + plaintext username + plaintext timestamp to server B (via a GET parameter in the redirect URL), on server B verify correctness and freshness.

If it is a sensitive application, I would rather look into some professional SSO solution.

One thing you should watch out for if you choose the homemade solution is the vulnerability of certain hashes (like MD5) to [length extension attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). Also, the syntax of `crypt` is notoriously easy to get wrong.

Comment: Would you recommend something particularin instead of crypt? Thanks.

Comment: [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) maybe, or just use `crypt` but read the docs carefully. I am not particularly experienced in or knowledgeable this area, I have just seen a lot of warnings about how the output of crypt depends on OS and other external conditions, and how its behavior can be unintuitive when its parameters are invalid.